# visual studio 2010 with cpp build tools 2015

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible to compile and debug full c++11 code with visual studio 2010 ? 
Is it possible to change the compiler of visual studio 2010 to use visual cpp 2015 build tools ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is it possible to compile and debug full c++11 code with visual studio 2010?

No, visual studio 2010 contain C++11 features, but not all of them, Here is a list of what features it supports (as well as VC++ 2015), I suggest that you could use visual studio 2015, which contain most of the features instead of Extended integer types

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

> > Is it possible to change the compiler of visual studio 2010 to use visual cpp 2015 build tools ?

No, it is impossible, we can only select  low-level Platform Toolset (such vs2008). So I suggest you could visual studio 2015.

Comment: *No, it is impossible,* wouldn't be to sure about that. Sure it might be a hack, and sure I fail to see *why* one would do that, but I think by copying the correct files around and modifying some stuff here and there it might be doable, given I once managed to use VS2010 toolsets in VS2008 which was arguable a bigger leap since there were a lot of core changes in the build system between those 2 versions, while from VS2010 on not much changed in how toolsets are defined.